# DevExpress Add items to ComboBox at run time

Tags: vb.net, combobox, devexpress

I've recently started using the [DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsComboBoxtopic) Comboboxes and other UI components. But I'm struggling to add items to the ComboBoxes during rune-time. The default Visual Basics's ComboBox worked simply by using the `Items.Add` code... But DevExpresses seam much more complicated, I've spent the last hour trying to work out how to add an item to the Combobox during run-time. And now this is my final option.

Has anyone got an idea on how this could be done? To be a little clearer, I'm trying something like this:

```
If combobox1.SelectectItem = "Item1" Then 
    Combobox2.items.add("Added Item String")
end if
```

just using syntax the DevExpress classes will 'understand'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `DevExpress` editors have the `SomeEditor.Properties` property which contains settings specific to the editors. So, you can get `Items` collection from `comboBox.Properties.Items` property:

```
If combobox1.SelectectItem.ToString = "Item1" Then 
    Combobox2.Properties.Items.Add("Added Item String")
End If
```

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up with the dropdownbutton and the combobox, that's why this code didn't work earlier. Thank you for your help.